# I want Python to process all xml files in a directory, but it only does the top one

Tags: python, xml, linux

I have an xml parser that was originally intended to be used with a single file, but was edited to process all files in a directory given directory and a wildcard. It is being run from a Linux server.
The command is subject to the following usage:

> -d, --directory   directory to read all files in one at a time; example -d /output/*.xml
>
> -f, --file      xml to read in; example: -f output.xml
>
> -o, --output      Filename of output file for HTML report

So, in this particular example, an example of what I'm trying to do would be written like

> python parser.py -d /Directory/Directory -w output*.xml

Here is my main()

```
def main():
     if (output != ''):
         if output.endswith('.html'):
             outFile = open(output, 'w')
         else:
             outFile = open(output + '.html', 'w')
     else:
         outFile = open('nmap-SMB-scan-output.html', 'w')

     if (inFile != ''):
         if not os.path.isfile(inFile):
             print('\nThere was an error opening file: %s (1)' % inFile)
             sys.exit()
         else:
             try:
                 outFile = header(outFile)
                 outFile = processFile(inFile, outFile)
                 outFile = footer(outFile)
             except:
                 print('\nThere was an error opening file: %s (2)' % inFile)

     elif (directory != ''):
         if (wildcard == ''):
             print('\nExiting, if using directory must use wildcard as well.')
             sys.exit()
         findFiles = directory + '/' + wildcard
         onlyfiles = glob.glob(findFiles)
         outFile = header(outFile)
         for f in onlyfiles:
             try:
                 outFile = processFile(f, outFile)
             except:
                 print('\nThere was an error opening file: %s (3)' % f)
         outFile = footer(outFile)

     else:  # if (inFile = '') and (directory = ''):
         print('\nYou must provide a file or directory to continue.')
         sys.exit()
```

The file is then kicked into the actual processing aspect, gets formatted, and hits this try statement:

```
try:
     opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "f:o:w:d:", ['file=', 'output=', 'wildcard=', 'directory='])
     inFile = output = directory = wildcard = ''
     proceed = False
     for opt, val in opts:
         if opt in ('-f', '--file'):
             if not os.path.isfile(val):
                 print('\nFile "%s" does not appear to exist, please verify file name.' % val)
                 sys.exit()
             else:
                 proceed = True
             inFile = val
         if opt in ('-o', '--output'):
             output = val
         if opt in ('-d', '--directory'):
             if not os.path.isdir(val):
                 print('\nDir "%s" does not appear to exist, please verify directory name.' % val)
                 sys.exit()
             else:
                 print("Directory selection:" + % val)
                 proceed = True
                 directory = val
         if opt in ('-w', '--wildcard'):
             wildcard = val

     if (__name__ == '__main__') and proceed == True:
         main()
     else:
         print('Need to provide a file or directory to process')
         usage()

 except getopt.error:
     usage()
```

I am not really sure why it is not looping back to main() to move on to the next file... any suggestions you could provide would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest spending some time with `ipdb` &/or `print`. And possibly `argparse` (optional)

Comment: There is a lot of code to get in fast. It is easy to ask. Do you process multiple files from arguments?  The wildcard does not go inside your code. It's expanded by cmd. If you want to parse wildcard yourself, you need to use quotes 'output*.xml'.